# google chrome error swf

Tags: google-chrome, flash

the newest version of google chrome [ 27.0.1453.94 m ] seems to have problem with loading/displaying couple of swf(flash) files at the same time.....

As I open my website [ http://www.msstudio.art.pl/index.php ]  in [ updated google chrome 27.0.1453.94 m ] there are 2 swf files but only one is loaded and displayed.

When page is refreshed a few times a second swf file is loaded/displayed.  So it seems error loading/displaying both swf files at the same time.... I have no idea what is the code error.

Other net browser display my www correctly and previous chrom browser was displaying my www without error too.

Answer (score 0):

I took out the embed and it seemed to fix the issue in chrome: